# Conditional Function Definition Best Practise

Tags: python

My coworker and I have been talking about some code that he wrote in a pull request. It involves defining a function within each branch of a conditional statement.

Original:

```
if is_something:     # constant, but unknown until runtime
    def do_thing():
        return 'x'
else:
    def do_thing():
        return 'y'

while True:
    # other code here
    foo = do_thing()
```

My first thought was to shift the conditional into the function definition and use it like that, but that does mean the condition is needlessly evaluated for every loop. 
My second thought was to define two different functions (with different names), then in a conditional to assign the correct function to a variable which is then later called in the loop.

Option 2:

```
def thing_x():
    return 'x'

def thing_y():
    return 'y'

if is_something:     # constant, but unknown until runtime
    thing_func = thing_x
else:
    thing_func = thing_y

while True:
    # other code here
    foo = thing_func()
```

I like this version better, but I can't articulate *why* I like this version better.

Is there any practical reason for one or the other, or is it just a "pick one" situation?

Comment: It's just a stylistic choice, they both do the same thing.  Option 2 seems more readable as the functions are defined outside the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with Option 2.  Defining a function inside an if statement is a poor way to organize your code.  If you group all your functions together it will be easier to read and maintain.  Pretend that you have left your company and someone else is trying to update your code.  You want it to be as readable as possible.

I know this is just your example snippet but I also wanted to point out that having a "while True" condition is also a bad idea as it could create an infinite loop.

Comment: So just more of a code readability aspect then. Okay. 
The `while True` part was just meant to mean "a big loop", in reality it's a loop over a large list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could do the following and then the code would even work if `is_something` switches:

```
def do_thing(is_something):
    if is_something:
        # Some code
    else:
        # Other code

while True:
    do_thing(is_something)
```

Comment: This has to test `is_something` every time you call it. It might be a temporary variable, or local to the function that needs to assign the function.

Comment: That's one option, but it does mean that the condition is evaluated on every loop. Our particular situation is static, but only known at runtime.

Comment: If it's guaranteed to be static then I can see why you wouldn't want to test it inside the function @MisterSheep

Answer (score 1):

Going for option 2 i would do the assignment like this:

```
thing_func = thing_x if is_something else thing_y #python's ternary operator
```

Answer (score -3):

Option 2 is more reasonable. We define function so that we can call them and use as and when necessary without rewriting the code again and again. I don't understand why you need to write a function within a condition. Assuming do_thing() is same function :
Original code can be written as:

```
def do_thing():
    return 'x'
if is_something:
     do_thing()
else:
    do_thing()
while True:
    # other code here
    foo = do_thing()
```

Comment: I think you might be missing that both `do_thing()` function definitions return different things.

Comment: yes, you are right. If they return diff things 'x' can be handled in the function itself to return as per the input parameter. Or if two functions are required then Option 2 would suffice.